# Python 3.7- SSL certificate error when excuting pip install Jupyter on command prompt

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ssl-certificate

I have an issue on installing python 3.7, and my OS is windows 10.

I installed Anaconda 3. When I open the command prompt and execute **pip install Jupyter**, I have error message as below:

***Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443)***

This is full message I've got.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uV6z9.png)

Is there any solution? Thanks in advances :D

Comment: Hi there, please look at this guide [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  Specifically don't insert images with code, please.

Answer (score 1):

trusted host  - **pypi.org** instead of pipi.org or pypi.python.org worked for me

```
pip install --upgrade pip --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org
```

Answer (score 0):

The warning message at the top of the image `pip is configured with locations that require...` means that you are having issues with communicating with PyPI.

Try either:

- Upgrade your pip by `pip install --upgrade pip --trusted-host pipi.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org`
- Disable SSL verification in your pip module.
  In your `pip` module in `site-packages`, open up `site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\sessions.py` and 
  Replace all `self.verify=True` into `self.verify=False`.

-- Edition:

Wrong host names arguments in the first fix option.

- Upgrade your pip by `pip install --upgrade pip --trusted-host pypi.python.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org`